# Draw an NSOutlineView background that tracks the last row

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am building an outliner in which users make notes. The NSOutlineView is in a NSScrollView which is the full height of the window. I would like to have a plain background behind the NSOutlineView that *exactly* tracks some margin below the bottom row in the outliner.

The scrollView has elasticity at the ends of its scrolling behaviour. The NSOutlineView animates when in expands/collapses. Users can add new rows, and typing in a row can increase the row height. This gives many variations of movement to the rows.

At the moment I am able to catch some changes in the position of the last row. I override and catch layout() on the NSOutlineView and catch boundsChangedNotifications on the scrollView contentView.

The problem is that layout() is only called on the outlineView at the beginning and end of animation sequences. If I animate changes to the background it almost tracks the same movement, but the animation breaks tracking of any scrollview motion.

I really need to catch updates each frame (as in render) and set the background height. How can I do this? Is there a far more simple way that I am missing?

I don't want to add fake rows to the outline view to to this, as it would make other functionality such as drag and drop very complex.

I am not using Interface Builder.

Comment: At the moment I am using a timer to update a layer in my background view every 0.01 seconds. It is OK, but I can see some lag in its movement relative to the outline rows in some situations. I would be great if I could make sure this was called after all animations were updated, but before drawing takes place. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe adding a CoreAnimation Action for the position, frame, or bounds of the layer for the last cell in the outline view and then doing your update in the action handler?  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ReactingtoLayerChanges/ReactingtoLayerChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH7-SW1 and https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH11-SW1 and related. Or maybe the layer for contentView?

Comment: Thanks @Dad. That looks to be just what I need. The content view doesn't seem to ever change, so I will try it out on the last row in time and post here.